# How do I make an activation link on registration expire in 15 minutes?

Tags: users, 9

I have user registration and forgot password mails sent to the user.

I want 5 minute expiration for forgot password and user registration. Now the forgot password will expire after 5 minutes but new user registration link is not expiring after 5 minutes.

I have set the following changes in settings.php.

But it is not working for first time activation link.

`$conf['user_password_reset_timeout'] = '259200';`

How do I make an activation link on registration expire in 15 minutes?

Comment: There isn't a question here.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal Core [doesn’t yet have this feature](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3097238). Contribute to the issue. Test and use patches there to help deliver the feature.

Answer (score 1):

The password reset timeout can be set by adding to **settings.php**

`$config['user.settings']['password_reset_timeout'] = 900;//15*60`